# How do I disable SASL in KMail?

Tags: dovecot, imap, sasl, kmail

I have a laptop running KMail 5.7.3 on Bionic Beaver. I just got a new computer with Eoan Ermine and am trying to set up Kmail 5.11.3 to use the same IMAP server. I set up the IMAP account, tried to view my email, and got this error:

```
The server for account "IMAP Account 1" refused the supplied username and password. Do you want to go to the settings, have another attempt at logging in, or do nothing?

SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found
```

I set it to plain text (which is safe since the server and both clients are in the same house) and ran Wireshark and captured this:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready.
A000001 LOGOUT
* BYE Logging out
A000001 OK Logout completed.
```

It didn't even try to log in! How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SASL` is just a set of authentication mechanisms, which are common to many protocols. It is the modern alternative to protocol specific authentication mechanisms (the `LOGIN` command in the case of `IMAP`) and is not the culprit here.

Dovecot has a configuration variable, which disables both `LOGIN` (you can see the `LOGINDISABLED` capability in dovecot's banner) and all plaintext `SASL` mechanisms, unless the connection is encrypted. You can switch it off by modifying:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
```

to

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
```

in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` and reloading **dovecot**.

Comment: Thanks! The comment in that file says "Note that if the remote IP matches the local IP ... plaintext authentication is allowed." I ran the connection over a forwarded port, making the connection appear to come from localhost, and it worked. Now I'll reload Dovecot and see what happens.